# pymongo - ifnull repacing the entire object instead of the the particular field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have the following document:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cae9aa015ee5fc8892a8)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {
        "value": [],
        "tag": "ACCOUNT_NO"
      },
      "doc_type_class_labels": ""
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cae9aa015ee5fc8892ab)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {
        "value": [
          {
            "start": 1019,
            "end": 1033,
            "text": "F10-749-113245",
            "tag": "ACCOUNT_NO",
            "color": "rgb(244, 10, 10, 0.527)"
          }
        ],
        "tag": "ACCOUNT_NO"
      },
      "doc_type_class_labels": "BL"
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cae9aa015ee5fc8892ae)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {
        "value": []
      },
      "doc_type_class_labels": ""
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cae9aa015ee5fc8892b1)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {
        "value": [
          {
            "start": 65,
            "end": 81,
            "text": "Nowhere BANK LTD ",
            "tag": "DRAWER",
            "color": "rgb(85, 239, 239, 0.527)"
          }
        ],
        "tag": "ACCOUNT_NO"
      },
      "doc_type_class_labels": "APPLICATION"
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cae9aa015ee5fc8892b4)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {
        "value": [],
        "tag": "ACCOUNT_NO"
      },
      "doc_type_class_labels": "APPLICATION"
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cae9aa015ee5fc8892b7)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {
        "value": []
      },
      "doc_type_class_labels": ""
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cbfdaa015ee5fc8892bf)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {
        "value": []
      },
      "doc_type_class_labels": ""
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cbfdaa015ee5fc8892c2)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {
        "value": []
      },
      "doc_type_class_labels": ""
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cbfdaa015ee5fc8892c5)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {
        "value": []
      },
      "doc_type_class_labels": ""
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cbfdaa015ee5fc8892c8)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {
        "value": []
      },
      "doc_type_class_labels": ""
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  }
]
```

I ran the following query to get my required data:

```
{
    '$unwind': {
        'path': '$annotations.ner_labels.value',
        "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": True
    }
},
```

I get the following output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cae9aa015ee5fc8892a8)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {
        "tag": "ACCOUNT_NO"
      },
      "doc_type_class_labels": ""
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cae9aa015ee5fc8892ab)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {
        "value": {
          "start": 1019,
          "end": 1033,
          "text": "F10-749-113245",
          "tag": "ACCOUNT_NO",
          "color": "rgb(244, 10, 10, 0.527)"
        },
        "tag": "ACCOUNT_NO"
      },
      "doc_type_class_labels": "BL"
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cae9aa015ee5fc8892ae)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {},
      "doc_type_class_labels": ""
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cae9aa015ee5fc8892b1)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {
        "value": {
          "start": 65,
          "end": 81,
          "text": "nowhere BANK LTD ",
          "tag": "DRAWER",
          "color": "rgb(85, 239, 239, 0.527)"
        },
        "tag": "ACCOUNT_NO"
      },
      "doc_type_class_labels": "APPLICATION"
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cae9aa015ee5fc8892b4)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {
        "tag": "ACCOUNT_NO"
      },
      "doc_type_class_labels": "APPLICATION"
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cae9aa015ee5fc8892b7)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {},
      "doc_type_class_labels": ""
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cbfdaa015ee5fc8892bf)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {},
      "doc_type_class_labels": ""
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cbfdaa015ee5fc8892c2)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {},
      "doc_type_class_labels": ""
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cbfdaa015ee5fc8892c5)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {},
      "doc_type_class_labels": ""
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cbfdaa015ee5fc8892c8)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {},
      "doc_type_class_labels": ""
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  }
]
```

The `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` is creating an `empty object`. Now i need to add a temporary value inside the `empty object`. So I used the following code:

```
{
    '$project': {
        'annotations.ner_labels.value': {
            '$ifNull': [
                '$annotations.ner_labels.value', [],
            ]
        },
        'category': 1,
        'job_id': 1
    }
},
```

After this the entire object is modified instead if the particular field, the following is the output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cae9aa015ee5fc8892a8)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {
        "value": []
      }
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cae9aa015ee5fc8892ab)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {
        "value": {
          "start": 1019,
          "end": 1033,
          "text": "F10-749-113245",
          "tag": "ACCOUNT_NO",
          "color": "rgb(244, 10, 10, 0.527)"
        }
      }
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cae9aa015ee5fc8892ae)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {
        "value": []
      }
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cae9aa015ee5fc8892b1)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {
        "value": {
          "start": 65,
          "end": 81,
          "text": "nowhere BANK LTD ",
          "tag": "DRAWER",
          "color": "rgb(85, 239, 239, 0.527)"
        }
      }
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cae9aa015ee5fc8892b4)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {
        "value": []
      }
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cae9aa015ee5fc8892b7)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {
        "value": []
      }
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cbfdaa015ee5fc8892bf)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {
        "value": []
      }
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cbfdaa015ee5fc8892c2)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {
        "value": []
      }
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cbfdaa015ee5fc8892c5)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {
        "value": []
      }
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cbfdaa015ee5fc8892c8)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {
        "value": []
      }
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
  }
]
```

The following

```
{
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cbfdaa015ee5fc8892c2)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {},
      "doc_type_class_labels": ""
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
}
```

is changed to the following after `ifnull`

```
{
    "_id": "ObjectId(6448cbfdaa015ee5fc8892c2)",
    "job_id": "ObjectId(6448cac2aa015ee5fc8892a0)",
    "annotations": {
      "ner_labels": {
        "value": []
      }
    },
    "category": "TEXT"
}
```

The field `doc_type_class_labels` is missing. How to change only the missing field instead of the entire object?
Kindly advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `$addFields` instead of `$project` since project will not show the fields that you do not include.
[The `$addFields` stage is equivalent to a `$project` stage that explicitly specifies all existing fields in the input documents and adds the new fields.](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#definition)

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kdPyr6TrkAe)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$annotations.ner_labels.value",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "annotations.ner_labels.value": {
        $ifNull: [
          "$annotations.ner_labels.value",
          []
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```